# alternative trigonometric proof to inequality problem

Tags: trigonometry, recreational-mathematics

[image]

This is the solution by using the inequality provided; However, I seem to not understand how this $$
\begin{aligned}
P & =14+5 \tan ^2 a+9 \cot ^2 a+\left(\tan ^2 b+4 \cot ^2 b\right)\left(1+\tan ^2 a\right) \\
& \geq 14+5 \tan ^2 a+9 \cot ^2 a+2 \tan b \cdot 2 \cot b\left(1+\tan ^2 a\right) \\\end{aligned}
$$ was converted to this $$ \begin{aligned} & =18+9\left(\tan ^2 a+\cot ^2 a\right) \geq 18+9 \cdot 2 \tan a \cot a=36 . \\\end{aligned}$$

I understand how the inquality on the bottom is equal to 36 but I do not understand how they converted all the trigonometric function with b's to a's , or rather, evaluated them.

Comment: Note $\tan b=\frac{\sin b}{\cos b}$ and $\cot b = \frac{\cos b}{\sin b}$, so $2 \tan b \cdot 2 \cot b = 4( \tan b \cdot \cot b) = 4(1) = 4$.

Comment: I am aware of that; however, how is $$ \left(\tan ^2 b+4 \cot ^2 b\right).$$ equal to 4? @JohnOmielan

Comment: Using $x^2+y^2\ge 2xy$ mentioned earlier in the solution, have $x=\tan b$ and $y=2\cot b$.

Comment: Not "equal to $4$". $\left(\tan ^2 b+4 \cot ^2 b\right) \ge 2\tan b \cdot 2\cot b$, using the main idea of this example: $x^2+y^2\ge 2xy$.

Comment: I see now, they are essentially the same it just that one is greater. However, It still seems strange to me how the portion to the left of the >=  is equal to $18+9\left(\tan ^2 a+\cot ^2 a\right)$. How did 14 turn to 18?

Comment: From $2\tan b\cdot 2\cot b=4$ I explained in my previous [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4743108/alternative-trigonometric-proof-to-inequality-problem#comment10060718_4743108), we get $2\tan b\cdot 2\cot b(1+\tan^{2}a) = 4(1+\tan^{2}a) = 4+4\tan^{2}a$, so then $14 + 4 = 18$ and $5\tan^{2}a+4\tan^{2}a=9\tan^{2}a$.